# Why to always run db:create when restarting containers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Following https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/ with a Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.3.3
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
COPY Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
COPY . /myapp
```

and a docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

it's said:

> - Stop the application = `docker-compose down`
> - Restart the application = `docker-compose up` AND `docker-compose run web rake db:create`

Why do we need to create the database every time we restart the containers? Normally we run `db:create` only once and from then on run `db:migrate` to run new migrations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you have to map your docker local postgresql data files to your own machine.

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - /var/data/myapp/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

with this line:

```
- /var/data/myapp/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
```

you'll map /var/data/myapp/postgres to your docker /var/lib/postgresql/data and doesn't matter if you down or not your docker-compose, it'll still be available to the next docker-compose up

Comment: Perfect! Only `rw` is deprecated.

Comment: And I'd not mount an absolute path. Just `- ./postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data`.